# How to use glob.glob to combine txt files and add a string to break up the txt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files, glob

I'd like to combine a bunch of txt files but I would also like to add something at the end of each file so I know where one file ends and the other begins (in this case I used "###############")

If I use individual files and read through them, this code works, but I would just like to be able to read through a directory of files by using glob.glob.  When I do so, I'm getting a blank outfile.  Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Thanks!

```
import glob
with open("concatenated.txt",'w') as outfile:
    for files in glob.glob('\\home\\wra\\Desktop\\combine\\*.txt'):
        for fname in files:
            with open(fname) as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read() +"\n\n##################\n\n")
```

Comment: Try forward slashes instead of backslashes in your path.

Comment: @Rawing thank you! New to this and get it still mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems (and 1 warning):

- Unix paths should have `'/'` as separator, not `\\`. Unix path format might work on Windows, but not the other way around.
- You can iterate directly on `glob.glob`. You could use either `filenames = glob.glob(...)` or `for filename in glob.glob(...)`
- `infile.read()` can be dangerous if `infile` is huge. You could write the file line by line.

---

```
import glob
with open("concatenated.txt",'w') as outfile:
    for filename in glob.glob('/home/wra/Desktop/combine/*.txt'):
        with open(filename) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
        outfile.write("\n\n##################\n\n")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! (only been using python for two months so still a newbie). Thanks a lot for the help!